# One journal for each topic, or combine several topics in one?

Tags: blog, journalism

Let's assume that I begin a written journal (which over time will be published online) about:

- My preferences towards music
- Inspirational art and photography
- Short stories that I read and enjoy

In my mind, the goal of this journal is not only to document my interests, but to also promote the bands, artists, photographers and authors who are mentioned.

Now let's assume that within 6 months, I begin to create my own Art, Photography, Literature and Music. It seems to me that creating a journal about this (my work process, rough workings, finished projects, alternative edits, etc.) would be a great thing to do.

But, even though each of these journals have their own content and goals, I feel there is a good reason for combining the content into one single writing project. Bearing in mind that my preferences in music, literature and art — documented in Journal A — is the inspiration for my own work and creations — documented in Journal B.

On the other hand, as one is primarily an interests journal, and the other is a project journal, I'm not sure if in practice they would go together as well as it looks in theory.

Alternatively, does this scenario work better the other way around — turning a project-based journal into one that documents the inspiration behind your work.

Comment: I swear this same question was asked last week.

Comment: Well if you could point me to it's answer that would be extremely helpful @F1Krazy

Comment: I couldn't find it, otherwise I would have done. I'll take another look when I get home.

Comment: @F1Krazy Similar feelings of *deja vu* here.. I suspect because of  a series of extremely similar questions across the network from [this user](https://stackexchange.com/users/13606467/w-h), the content (and style) of the questions is.. familiar.

Comment: Also please be aware that [cross posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) the exact same question across multiple sites (in this case Writing and [Community Building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3162/twitter-accounts-single-topic-or-multiple-topics-in-one-account)) is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @motosubatsu The same question applies in both cases, so why not ask in 2 places!

Comment: @WSix The FAQ answer in the link I gave explains why cross posting is generally considered a bad thing and how you should go about it if you do, TBH if I think this is on-topic on either it's here rather than on Community Building, but (and I'm sorry if this sounds harsh) I think you're actually a bad-faith user with multiple sock puppets.

Comment: Just a user trying to get some answers - And it would be appreciated if people like yourself would simply answer the question at hand, rather than try to think up reasons why a post may be off topic, or somehow similar to another question posted months ago, or debate whether someone may be a troll with multiple accounts. If you're an admin please just delete my posts ( and any you think may be posted by one of my many alter ego's )

Comment: @WSix I'm not an admin/mod so you have no fear of any delete-hammers from me. Also I was actually positing that this question **was** on topic here. Now I may be wrong about you being who I think you are but I'd go so far as to say I'm 90% certain that you **are**, multiple accounts aren't unilaterally forbidden AFAIK unless they are being used to [circumvent SE rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange/57685#57685) but it is disingenuous at best IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Start writing. Stop asking questions about format or you will never get anything written. It doesn't matter whether you are writing about more than one topic in a single journal or more than one. Get a body of written text and then worry about its exact form.

The bottom line is, until you start writing, your questions are immaterial: you can't publish articles that have never been written.

Comment: That is very true, but I would like to address these concerns sooner rather than later as I have found that in the past, not planning ahead has had a negative impact on my workflow ( when I was blogging ).